# Why do I get only JSON as output of the REST web service?

Tags: xml, json, delphi, rest, c++builder

I'm playing a little bit with REST Clients in C++ Builder and I'm connecting to http://api.discogs.com. For example:

http://api.discogs.com/artist/Michael+Jackson

When visiting this web page the output is sometimes JSON and sometimes XML, while my desktop rest client application that connects to this service always gets the result in JSON format.

Why is this happening and can I force my desktop REST client to get the response in XML?

Rest client settings:
Accept : application/json, text/plain; q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8

I suspect this is where I need to change things but don't know how.

Comment: Sometimes, there is a parameter in the REST call that allows you to specify whether the response is in JSON or XML. I've seen this a few times. It is up to the API developer though to support either or both output formats.

Comment: Yes. That is the parameter ' f '. For example, as @mjn specified below it can be f=xml (xml format) or f=json (json format).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is still support for XML responses. To verify, try this link:

http://api.discogs.com/artist/Michael+Jackson?f=xml

(found at_ http://www.discogs.com/help/forums/topic/326725)

Comment: I will accept this answer since it showed additional parameter (f) that can be used to define REST output.